# Shipping Method Canada Post

Tags: api, shipping, shipping-methods

Is there any free shipping method plugin for Canada Post . There are two plugins in magento marketplace for canada post but they are very expensive.
Thanks

Comment: "Shopping list" questions are not a good fit for StackExchange Q&A
(see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad) -
you'll get better results at the Magento forums (https://community.magento.com/t5/Find-an-Extension-that/bd-p/find-extension)
or Reddit (http://www.reddit.com/r/Magento)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [This Link](http://cedcommerce.com/magento-extensions/canada-post-shipping) Help You . Not Free Module But Not Much Expensive too.

Comment: can we build our plugin for canada post ?

Comment: yes we can build our plugin for that but must having a good knowledge of magento .

Comment: can you guide me to how to build your own shipping module

Comment: have you created any custom module before?

Comment: No but i want to learn

Comment: http://kamleshkamble.blogspot.in/2013/02/custom-module-in-magento-with-custom.html

Comment: go for above link to create first simple custom module in magento